# QWEB - IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8, qweb

I'm trying to create a QWeb report. I have a list of product and I would like to print each etiquette on the same page. This is my code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
        <!-- Déclaration des rapports -->
            <report 
                id="etiquette_produit"
                model="product.template"
                string="Etiquette Produit"
                report_type="qweb-pdf"
                file="Product_Etiquette_QWeb.produit_etiquette"
                name="Product_Etiquette_QWeb.produit_etiquette"
            />

        <template id="produit_etiquette">
            <t t-call="report.external_layout">
                <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
                    <div class="page">
                        <table class="table table-striped">
                            <tr>
                                <td class="col-xs-1"><span t-field="o.default_code"/></td>
                                <td class="col-xs-5 text-center"><span t-field="o.name"/></td>
                                <td class="col-xs-1"><span t-field="o.default_code"/></td>
                                <td class="col-xs-5 text-center"><span t-field="o.name"/></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2" class="text-center">* M E 2 1 5 9 *</td>
                                <td colspan="2" class="text-center">* M E 2 0 1 7 *</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </t>
            </t>
        </template>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

The problem : When I select all the products to print, i have an error (see below). But when i select only one product, i can print the report.

```
Odoo Server Error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/addons/report/controllers/main.py", line 116, in report_download
    response = self.report_routes(reportname, docids=docids, converter='pdf')
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/http.py", line 405, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/addons/report/controllers/main.py", line 65, in report_routes
    pdf = report_obj.get_pdf(cr, uid, docids, reportname, data=options_data, context=context)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/api.py", line 268, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/addons/report/models/report.py", line 275, in get_pdf
    paperformat, specific_paperformat_args, save_in_attachment
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/api.py", line 268, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/addons/report/models/report.py", line 432, in _run_wkhtmltopdf
    head_file.write(headers[index])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue is related to the fact that the report engine expects to have 1 header and footer for each page. You are creating N pages for 1 header+footer.

The call `<t t-call="report.external_layout">` must be put inside the for loop. If you need more than one item in the same page do not use `page` class as wrapper, since that is what it used by the engine to fetch report pages. You can have a look at the [source code](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8.0/addons/report/models/report.py#L228).